# tfma.view.render_slicing_metrics not working

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-analysis, tfx

I am trying to visualize model results using `tfma.view.render_slicing_metrics`. I am getting the results with `tfma.load_eval_result(tfma_artifact.uri)` and I am able to print the results.

```
[EvalResult(slicing_metrics=[((('trip_start_hour', 2),), {'precision': {'doubleValue': 0.6666666865348816}, 'accuracy_baseline': {'doubleValue': 0.8188405632972717},
...................................
'predictioexample_weight_metric_key='post_export_metrics/example_count', num_bootstrap_samples=1))]
```

But when I try to visualize the results with `tfma.view.render_slicing_metrics(tfma.load_eval_result(tfma_artifact.uri))` I am seeing a empty visualization.

```py
import tensorflow_model_analysis as tfma
tfma_artifact = store.get_dest_artifact_of_type(11,'ModelEvalPath')
tfma.load_eval_result(tfma_artifact.uri)
tfma.view.render_slicing_metrics(tfma.load_eval_result(tfma_artifact.uri))
```

Comment: Check your browser logs. That might be an issue loading the Jupyter extension.

Comment: For me this was an issue with running TensorFlow, TensorBoard and JupyterNotebook in a docker container. Ports 6006, 6007, 6008 ... etc. get used in ascending order and these need to be exposed to allow the browser to connect.